# Traminer: Mean time barplot with number of observations

Tags: r, dataframe, traminer

Because I am still new to TraMineR, my problem may seem trivial to most of you. I'm working on meantime plots with my data and would I like to plot on the bar charts the mean time spent in different states. is there a command in TramineR?

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the best answers quickly, using a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is best. However, since TraMineR uses base R plotting, you can use the function `text()` to add text.

Comment: @Kat Many thanks this is the code the calculates the mean times. How can I use the text()function? res <- by(df_new.seq, cl1.4fac, seqmeant)
mres <- matrix(unlist(res), nrow=nrow(res[[1]]), byrow=FALSE)
rownames(mres) <- rownames(res[[1]])

Comment: I'm not sure what any of your objects are called, so it's pretty difficult to give you a good answer. `text(x = 1:length(meantimesObject), y = max(meantimesObject), labels = meantimesObject)`  - you will likely have to adjust the position of the labels, as well. You would have to provide a reproducible example to get a better answer, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option to add bar labels on the mean time plot has been implemented in version TraMineR v 2.2-3.  The option is available through the arguments `bar.labels`, `cex.barlab`, and `offset.barlab` of the `plot` method for the outcome of `seqmeant`. These arguments can be passed as `...` arguments to `seqmtplot`. In this latter case, when groups are specified, `bar.labels` should be a matrix with the labels for each group in columns.

I show, using the `actcal` data, how to display the meant times over the bars. The group is here `sex`, but can of course be your clusters.

```
library(TraMineR)
data(actcal)
## We use only a sample of 300 cases
set.seed(1)
actcal <- actcal[sample(nrow(actcal),300),]
actcal.lab <- c("> 37 hours", "19-36 hours", "1-18 hours", "no work")
actcal.seq <- seqdef(actcal,13:24,labels=actcal.lab)

group <- factor(actcal$sex)
blab <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(levels(group))){
  blab <- cbind(blab,seqmeant(actcal.seq[group==levels(group)[i],]))
}
seqmtplot(actcal.seq, group=group,
          bar.labels = round(blab,digits=2), cex.barlab=1.2)
```

[image]